# how to get public key from getSigningKey function of jwks-rsa

Tags: node.js

i have tried two library of nodejs "jwks-rsa" and "jwks-client" to get public key to authenticate Apple login. But its giving error in getPublicKey is not a function.
Then i console the  key which is return by getSigningKey is giving me -1.
i don't know why this is behaving like that.

```
 const header = token.split(".");
        const jwtHead = Buffer.from(header[0], "base64").toString();
        const kid = JSON.parse(jwtHead).kid;

const jwksClient = require('jwks-client');
     const client = jwksClient({
          strictSsl: true, // Default value
          jwksUri:  process.env.APPLE_URL
        });

 client.getSigningKey(kid, (err, key) => {
            console.log(key)
          const signingKey = key.publicKey;
          console.log(signingKey);
        });
```

Comment: are you sure that `kid` is legit and your `jwksUri` is correct?

Comment: Yes i am fully sure

Comment: and you can find that `kid` inside your `jwksUri` key value? or is there any errors on getSigninKey call?

Comment: getSigning key returns me -1

Comment: its not returning me the public key and other things which it returns

Comment: your `jwksUri` should be the key vault where should be some key with your `kid` and if there isn't any key with that id than it's misconfiguration and it can't return anything to you

Comment: i fire this url https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys

Comment: and your `kid` should be "86D88Kf" or "eXaunmL" is that true?

Comment: Yes sir i have you two token and these are their kid

Comment: very strange is there any error returning?

Comment: i also surprised with it and searched many things but not got any success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works as expected I've try it with your configuration:

```
 const kid = '86D88Kf'; // specify kid explicitly
 const client = jwksClient({
      strictSsl: true,
      jwksUri:  'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys'
    });

 client.getSigningKey(kid, (err, key) => {
          console.log(key)
          const signingKey = key.publicKey;
          console.log(signingKey);
        });
```

And I get a legit public key in the response:

[image]

Probably you have some misconfiguration.

Comment: sir i can't able to run this in express and when i run it in serverless i got the same as you show here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `find()` method used inside `getSigningKey(kid).find()` method has compatibility issues [find() compatibility issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21fLK.png). We can use `filter()` method instead.

Instead of using `client.getSigningKey(kid)` try using `keys = client.getSigningKeys()` then filter the response  `const key = keys.filter(k => k.kid === kid);`